# Replacing a single character by a substring in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace any character that is not a: (letter, '.', '_', '-') by a string of characters, however re.sub always replaces the whole string instead of just the one character.

```
xmlreplace=re.compile("((?i)[^\w\_\-\.])", re.UNICODE)
print(xmlreplace.sub("regex test","-"))
```

expected output: "regex-test"

actual output: "-"

Comment: how many replacement do you want? It has an extra parameter `count` which can be used to limit the number of replacement

Comment: @rock321987 I'd like it to replace all occurences of the undesired characters

Comment: Regex patterns should use raw strings `r"..."`.

Comment: Actually `"((?i)[^\w\_\-\.])" == r"((?i)[^\w\_\-\.])"`, you can test it.

Comment: @AlexHall: you were right it doesn't change anything since escape sequences don't have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are unordered. It should be

```
print(xmlreplace.sub("-" , "regex test"))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/E5sAUx)**

If you want you can use `re.sub()`.

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
```

then, it should be

```
xmlreplace=re.compile("((?i)[^\w\_\-\.])", re.UNICODE)
print(re.sub(xmlreplace, "-" , "regex test"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are the wrong way round.

```
>>> help(xmlreplace.sub)
Help on built-in function sub:

sub(...)
    sub(repl, string[, count = 0]) --> newstring
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
    occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.
>>> print(xmlreplace.sub("-", "regex test"))
regex-test
```